# How to disable turbolinks for pagination links created by Kaminari gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, kaminari

I want to disable `turbolinks` for links created by kaminari gem. I tried following with no luck.

`<%= paginate audits, turbolinks: false %>`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: which html generates this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create custom views (bootstrap-4 is only example, you can choose something different):

```
rails g kaminari:views bootstrap4
```

This generates folder *kaminari* and all required views. Then you can customise links, in your case by adding additional attribute,

```
<li class="page-item">
  <%= link_to_unless current_page.last?, raw(t 'views.pagination.next'), url, rel: 'next', remote: remote, class: 'page-link', data: { turbolinks: false } %>
</li>
```

Comment: This would be my final solution if I don't find any other way. I am looking for an option to pass as it did for 'remote: true'.

Comment: Finally I end up with doing in this way only. It worked. But instead of just `turbolinks: false`, I had to use `data: {turbolinks: false}`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the information! I just edited my answer. You could mark the anwer as correct.